# How to install Siege on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to install Siege on Cygwin but I cannot find the install in the install packages on Cygwin.  Would it be coming under a different name?

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just compiled and installed Siege from source on CYGWIN without any problems.

My setup:

- Windows 7/64-Bit
- Cygwin 1.7.5 (gcc 3.4.4, make 3.81)
- Siege 2.70

Instructions:

- get the the latest source tarball from the [website](ftp://ftp.joedog.org/pub/siege/siege-2.70.tar.gz) and extract it
- `cd` to the extracted directory
- read the INSTALL file!
- run the configure script with the any configuation options that you may need, like the location of your SSL installation:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/ssl
```

- run `make` and `make
  install`
- check your installation:

```
$ siege --version
SIEGE 2.70

Copyright (C) 2010 by Jeffrey Fulmer, et al.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

- Done!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the HTTP benchmarking/testing tool (if not, you need to add a link to the specific thing you are talking about in your question as there could be any number of programs with that name), if it isn't in the standard cygwin package list you will probably need to install GCC and the required library dependencies and compile Siege from source.